# How do I change the background color after the end of my website for browsers that allow you to scroll past the end of the website?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

If you use **Edge** or **Safari on mobile** *(the only two I know for certain, but could be more)* you will see that you are able to scroll past the end and also the top of any website before it the browser automatically pushes you back into bounds of the web page. This is obviously an intended feature and a cool effect on those browsers, but it doesn't look to good when the colors arent matching.

I understand that the background color which is shown is the `body` elements `background-color`. However, this poses an issue for me. If my websites background color is white, but my footer is black, it ends up looking really awkward when the color changes to white again when you scroll past the footer. The issue gets even more tough if my navbar at the top is lets say red and I therefore need the area above my page to be red. Is there any properties I can use to change the background color of the area above and below my page? or can I position a div underneath the end of my page with black background color and if so how do I do that? or how do I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried setting a gradient like `background: linear-gradient(0deg, red 50%, green 50%);` ? So the top half of the body background will be red and the bottom half will be green for example

Answer (score 0):

The first solution would be to give your `<body>` the background color of the footer and to then wrap your content inside a container which has the page's background color (e. g. white):

```
<body style="background: var(--footer-background)">
  <main style="background: var(--content-background)">
    <!-- main content -->
  </main>
  <footer>
    <!-- footer content -->
  </footer>
</body>
```

I tested this on both Safari and Edge on an iPad.

---

In Safari, you can also use the [theme-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name/theme-color) meta attribute to specify the color of the overscroll area:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#4285f4">
```

However, this **did not seam to work on Edge** and is only supported on Safari since [version 15](https://webkit.org/blog/11989/new-webkit-features-in-safari-15/) with **"[compact tabs](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/tabs-ibrw1045/mac)" enabled**.

Comment: I tried the meta theme-color tag but it didnt do anything on safari on my phone unfortunatly. Maybe I have an old IOS idk

Comment: After some further testing, `theme-color` only sets the overscroll color when the "[compact tabs](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/tabs-ibrw1045/mac)" layout is used in Safari.
But the first solution I suggested still works everywhere I tested it.

Comment: I have now updated my original answer, thanks!